# undefined method `run' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, web-deployment

i'm getting the following output when deploying:

```
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `run' for main:Object
config/deploy.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:12:in `block in after'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:permissions
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `run' for main:Object>
```

i'm using Capistrano Version: 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.3.2).
the deploy works fine but i created a after deploy task to modify the owner of the deployed release which looks so:

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :permissions do
      run "chown -R :#{fetch(:group)} #{deploy_to} && chmod -R g+s #{deploy_to}"
    end
end

after :deploy, "deploy:permissions"
```

vars are defined correctly (i fixed that error before) but i get this missing method error for the run method and i dont know why.

Comment: it works now when specifying where i want to run the code by calling `on`. and i have to replace the run command with the execute command, too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code uses 2.x syntax, while your version is 3.x. In 3.x, the syntax looks like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  on roles :all do
    execute :chown, "-R :#{fetch(:group)} #{deploy_to} && chmod -R g+s #{deploy_to}"
  end
end
```

Comment: i think i mixed some how-tos for different cap versions.

it works now, so thx!

Comment: @Gergo Erdosi: What might be the equivalent of `namespace :myapp do
   task :restart_webserver do
      # Restart Web Server
      run "sudo service apache2 restart"
   end
end
after "deploy","myapp:restart_webserver"`