# NoMethodError: undefined method `execute' or 'run' capistrano 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

I am trying to call a php script after deployment in my capistrano script by I am getting the below error if I try execute

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `execute' for main:Object
```

If I try run I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `run' for main:Object
```

Below is the script which I am using

```
namespace :deploy do
        task :run_sql do
            run  "php -q /home/mydir/public_html/index.php argumen1 argument2 argument3 argument4"  
        end
end
after :deploy, "deploy:run_sql"
```

any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

PS: I will execute this one after deploy once my code gets deployed and this php file is on the server where I am deploying to.

Comment: can you show the full script and its location?

Comment: You didn't answer the execute problem - it looks like the method isn't there for some reason. I think run is a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is for 2.x version. Please refer here: [undefined method `run' for main:Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850404/undefined-method-run-for-mainobject#answer-23850488)

```
namespace :deploy do
  on roles :all do
    execute :php, "-q /home/mydir/public_html/index.php argumen1 argument2 argument3 argument4"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ariahnt - you're missing the on roles(:all) block - when you have that then it works.